# Find the first element that appears multiple times in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array, what's the best way to find the first element in it that appears more than `num` number of times? For example, in a Python list, similar job can be done as:

```
lst = np.random.randint(0,1000,1000000)
num = 100
next(el for el in lst if lst.count(el) > num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def first_value_occurs_more_than_n_times(array, n):
    for value in array:
        count = np.count_nonzero(array == value)
        if count > n:
            return value

# or just like your example:
next(value for value in array if np.count_nonzero(array == value) > num)
```